# Calling Python file in Prolog Program

Tags: python, text, prolog, text-to-speech, swi-prolog

I want to use a python file in my prolog code. I want to pass the text generated in prolog into text_to_speech_converter of python.How can I do it? I prefer to keep the interface of prolog only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `shell/2`

From http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=shell/2

```
?- shell('cmd.exe /C copy file1.txt file2.txt').
```

Then your python script should be called as usual from shell

```
?- shell('cmd.exe /C python hello.py > out.txt').
```

Comment: I need to enter the output text from prolog as input to python text_to_speech on prolog terminal dynamically. Please help.

Comment: input redirection ( `<`) should work as well (not tested sorry)